# Does it make sense to try to extend the concept of a raised set to a real number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, exponentiation

The definition of $a^b$ when $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers involves repeated multiplication. This definition can be extended to arbitrary exponents, motivated by the desire to preserve the identity $a^x\times a^y=a^{x+y}$.

Is it possible to extend the definition of the cartesian product in an analogous manner? It is clear what $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ means, but it is not obvious how $\mathbb R^{t}$ should be defined for arbitrary real values of $t$.

Comment: Cantor and other workers on the foundations on mathematics beat you to the paper by 120 years or so.

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: The notion of the set ($A^B$) of all functions between two sets $A$ and $B$ was investigated by Cantor and others many years ago. It is down to you to see if you can come up with an interesting interpretation of the concept when $B$ is viewed as a real number $t$ in some interesting way.

Comment: Exactly, curious that no one has thought about it yet

Comment: Well, to start, A^(1/2) x A^(1/2) should be (isomorphic to) A. That already looks weird for arbitrary sets A.

Comment: I don't understand why people have downvoted your question.  It seemed to me it was asked in good faith.  And as I was at some pains to point out, the question is mathematically reasonable and has been the subject of serious study.  This kind of question is one of the ways that mathematics advances: someone asks, could we make sense of $A^2$ when $A$ is a set instead of a number, and the answer is yes; someone else asks if there is a way to make sense of $\Bbb R^n$ when $n$ is a fraction, and the answer is no. Don't let the haters discourage you.

Comment: Its relevance to this question is dubious, but, in a sense, in theoretical physics, [dimensional regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization) more specifically, they calculate integrals over a space of dimension $d$, treating $d$ as a complex variable. The value of the integral then usually has a pole at a relevant value $d=4$, but something physically relevant can be extracted from whatever remains after cancelling that pole.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately there really isn't anything like that. This is a reasonable question to ask.  We *can* generalize ordinary exponentiation to work on sets instead of numbers, and all the familiar properties still hold, if you interpret them correctly.  For example, we can say that $\Bbb R^2 \times\Bbb R^1 = \Bbb R^3$ and have it mean something interesting and useful.

To make it work we have to interpret “$2$” and “$3$” as sets with $2$ and $3$ elements.  But this doesn't work for $\Bbb R^{1.5}$ because the idea of a set with $1.5$ elements seems meaningless.  Perhaps we could make sense of it somehow?  This has been investigated and the answer is: probably not.  If we did make sense of it, then whatever $\Bbb R^{1.5}$ should mean, it ought to at least have the property that $$\Bbb R^{1.5} \times \Bbb R^{1.5} = \Bbb R^3.$$

Could we find some mathematical object that behaves like this? This question has been addressed in the mathematical literature, and the answer is known:  there is no such object.

- "Another Proof That $\Bbb R^3$ Has No Square Root", Sam B. Nadler, Jr., *American Mathematical Monthly* vol 111 June–July 2004, pp. 527–528.
- "$\Bbb R^3$ Has No Root", Robbert Fokkink, *American Mathematical Monthly* vol 109 March 2002, p. 285

You can make anything work if you are willing to ignore enough of the ways in which it doesn't work. But the only way to make this work seems to be to disregard *all* the interesting special structure of $\Bbb R^3$. For example, if you were to interpret “$=$” so that  $\Bbb R^3 = \Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R$, you could perhaps make $\Bbb R^{1.5}$ work.  I think this isn't what you want though.

(I like the Fokkink paper better, it's simpler.)

Comment: For the references to apply, one has to add some context here. Namely, one should treat $R^x$ as a topological space and then ask if there is a topological space $R^{1.5}$ such that $R^{1.5}\times R^{1.5}$ is homeomorphic to $R^3$. Otherwise, it is a solid answer to an ill-posed question.

Comment: I was trying to get at this point in the last paragraph. $\Bbb R$ can be understood in many ways: it is an uncountable set, it is a topological space, it is a vector space, it is a field, etc. Sometimes you can extend an idea and  preserve some kinds of structure but not others. (For example, $\Bbb C$ can be a field, but not an ordered one.) But even when we consider the very small amount of structure required for a topological space, there are solid reasons why $\Bbb R^{1.5}$ cannot make sense.

Comment: I disagree that the question is “ill-posed”.  As I pointed out in my comment: “This kind of question is one of the ways that mathematics advances: someone asks, could we make sense of $A^2$ when $A$ is a set instead of a number, and the answer is yes; someone else asks if there is a way to make sense of $\Bbb R^n$ when $n$ is a fraction, and the answer is no.” The question “can we make this idea work in a more general context” is quintessentially mathematical.

Comment: Incidentally my suggestion that “if you were to interpret “$=$” so that  $\Bbb R^3 = \Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R$…” was not intended to be facetious.  If “$=$” is equinumerocity, we reach this result, at the cost of “disregarding all the interesting special structure of $\Bbb R$”.

Comment: In addition to equinumerocity the spaces $\Bbb{R}^n, n=1,2,3$, are all isomorphic as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$ (assuming the axiom of choice). Hence also as abstract groups. But surely here we want the fractional power itself to be distinct from the integer powers? A nice find/reference anyway.